# Is it possible to make Akismet asynchronous?

Tags: spam-prevention, spam

I'm using Akismet to block comment spam, but sometimes it takes way too long for the response to come back from Akismet. I'm not talking about just a few milliseconds - I'm talking about many seconds, and even close to a minute in some rare cases.

Is there a way to make Akismet asynchronous? By that I mean, it sends an API call to Akismet, but immediately returns to the blog post. It could by default accept the comment, but as soon as Akismet is done, it could update me. If the blog comment was spam, it'll delete it. If it wasn't, all's good.

Is there anyway to do this? Do I have to write my own anti-spam service if I want to do this? is this even feasible - will it require a lot of work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They get slow. We use them and it fluctuates depending on their server load.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely no reason you should see a response time like that.  The actual processing time is always sub-100ms.  Network lag can add to that, but we're always in two major data centers in the US, so you should see fast response times.

https://akismet.com/contact/ - get in touch and we'll help track down the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at Impermium http://impermium.com/. They're response time are generally about 2.5 ms.

Comment: why a downmod? I know it doesn't answer the original question but at the end of the question he offers up suggestions including writing his own or wondering if there is anyway to do it. I answered those just fine.

Comment: Umm.. they're not even a finished product.

Comment: Haha, yeah they are. You just need to know the right people:) They're running on a handful of very popular sites right now. But fair enough.

Comment: I wouldn't even want to use it anyway even if I knew the right people.